# Django use of readonly_fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been experimenting with the Django admin,

Can someone explain what use readonly_fields have and what difference it makes of just having the field as part of list_display and not on list_editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `readonly_fields` applies to the **edit view for a single object** rather than the **list view** for all objects.

In the list view, `list_editable` controls what can be edited directly from the list view, and `list_display` controls what model fields are displayed in the list.

In the individual edit view, [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) controls which fields are displayed but not editable. All other fields will be editable through the `ModelForm`:

> By default the admin shows all fields as editable. Any fields in this option will display its data as-is and non-editable; they are also excluded from the `ModelForm` used for creating and editing.